# Transform on groupby object returns false values which should be zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with roughly ~1000 rows, showing data about test-runs.

Some of those test-runs have an evaluation time of 0, meaning their execution time was **under 1 min**, thus not relevant.

However, when I'm accumulating the run times and returning it to a dataframe containing only the unique test-keys, all zero-values and some single-one's are filled with the data of the last test-run with data. (apparantly)

Below is my code but only applied to a cutout from the actual data.

```py
cols = ['Test key', 'Elapsed Time']
tests = ['HCSSYSTEST-1676', 'HCSSYSTEST-1518',
         'HCSSYSTEST-1658', 'HCSSYSTEST-1123']
filt = df_runs['Test key'].isin(tests)
df_cutout = df_runs[filt][cols]

print(df_cutout)

unique_cases = pd.DataFrame(df_cutout['Test key'].unique(), columns=['Test key'])
unique_cases['Run count'] = unique_cases['Test key'].map(df_cutout['Test key'].value_counts())
unique_cases['Accumulated Time'] = df_cutout.groupby('Test key')['Elapsed Time'].transform('sum')

print(unique_cases)
for test in tests:
    testFilter = (df_cutout['Test key'] == test)
    print("Elapsed Time of {} should be: {}".format(test, df_cutout[testFilter]['Elapsed Time'].sum()))
```

I assume, my application of `transform()` is wrong here, but I don't really understand why?

Here is the output:

```
Raw data:
             Test key    Elapsed Time
0     HCSSYSTEST-1676 0 days 00:44:00
1     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:22:00
2     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:15:00
3     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:20:00
4     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:20:00
5     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:04:00
6     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:13:00
7     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:12:00
8     HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:04:00
9     HCSSYSTEST-1676 0 days 00:01:00
10    HCSSYSTEST-1676 0 days 03:34:00
11    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
12    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:02:00
13    HCSSYSTEST-1658 0 days 00:00:00
19    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:02:00
20    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:03:00
21    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:04:00
22    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:03:00
23    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:01:00
37    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
38    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:01:00
39    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:38:00
40    HCSSYSTEST-1658 0 days 00:00:00
78    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:01:00
88    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
89    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:23:00
90    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:08:00
91    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
92    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:11:00
93    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
94    HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:06:00
163   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 01:31:00
199   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:22:00
200   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:00:00
201   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:10:00
202   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:08:00
203   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:02:00
204   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:04:00
205   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:02:00
206   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 02:02:00
207   HCSSYSTEST-1518 0 days 00:03:00
1022  HCSSYSTEST-1123 0 days 00:02:00
Aggregated data:
          Test key  Run count Accumulated Time
0  HCSSYSTEST-1676          3  0 days 04:19:00
1  HCSSYSTEST-1518         36  0 days 07:57:00
2  HCSSYSTEST-1658          2  0 days 07:57:00
3  HCSSYSTEST-1123          1  0 days 07:57:00
Comparison:
Elapsed Time of HCSSYSTEST-1676 should be: 0 days 04:19:00
Elapsed Time of HCSSYSTEST-1518 should be: 0 days 07:57:00
Elapsed Time of HCSSYSTEST-1658 should be: 0 days 00:00:00
Elapsed Time of HCSSYSTEST-1123 should be: 0 days 00:02:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I gathered to solve this:

`df_cutout.groupby('Test key')['Elapsed Time']` returns a SeriesGroupBy object and when I run `transform('sum')` it creates a dataframe with the same size as the original dataframe. *(Because that's what transform is supposed to be doing. I applied the wrong function)*

But when I assign this to another dataframe, I'm basically writing to different indices and thus getting back weird/incorrect values.

Instead I should aggregate and merge the resulting dataframe to get the results I want.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```py
cols = ['Test key', 'Elapsed Time']
tests = ['HCSSYSTEST-1676', 'HCSSYSTEST-1518',
         'HCSSYSTEST-1658', 'HCSSYSTEST-1123',
         'HCSSYSTEST-1663', 'HCSSYSTEST-1660']
filt = df_runs['Test key'].isin(tests)
df_cutout = df_runs[filt][cols]

print("Raw data:")
print(df_cutout)

unique_cases = pd.DataFrame(df_cutout['Test key'].unique(), columns=['Test key'])
unique_cases.set_index('Test key')
unique_cases['Run count'] = unique_cases['Test key'].map(df_cutout['Test key'].value_counts())
tmp = df_cutout.groupby('Test key').agg({'Elapsed Time': 'sum'})
unique_cases = unique_cases.merge(tmp, on='Test key')
# unique_cases['Accumulated Time v2'] = unique_cases['Test key'].map(df_cutout[['Test key', 'Elapsed Time']].sum())

print("Aggregated data:")
print(unique_cases)
print("Comparison:")
for test in tests:
    testFilter = (df_cutout['Test key'] == test)
    print("Elapsed Time of {} should be: {}".format(test, df_cutout[testFilter]['Elapsed Time'].sum()))
```

Result:

```
Aggregated data:
          Test key  Run count    Elapsed Time
0  HCSSYSTEST-1676          3 0 days 04:19:00
1  HCSSYSTEST-1518         36 0 days 07:57:00
2  HCSSYSTEST-1658          2 0 days 00:00:00
3  HCSSYSTEST-1663          1 0 days 00:02:00
4  HCSSYSTEST-1660          1 0 days 00:04:00
5  HCSSYSTEST-1123          1 0 days 00:02:00
```

There might be a better solution but that's what I've come up with.